# Why is audio generated by avconv choppy?

Tags: audio, encoding, avconv

I am using avconv to generate an AV stream, and the video is perfect, but the audio is very choppy using iOS Safari. 
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my audio stream that's causing this?
When playing using VLC on Mac it is also choppy, but when using some Flash players and OPlayer Lite on iOS it's fine.

I have attached a file containing only audio (exhibiting the same problem) [here](https://infotomb.com/6ig8p):

This is my full command line

`gst-launch-1.0 -v -e uvch264src profile=high iframe-period=20 device=/dev/video0 name=src auto-start=true src.vidsrc ! queue ! video/x-h264,width=800,height=600,framerate=20/1 ! omxh264dec ! omxh264enc target-bitrate=750000 control-rate=variable ! video/x-h264,profile=high ! h264parse ! queue ! flvmux streamable=true name=mux alsasrc device=hw:1 do-timestamp=true ! audioconvert ! audio/x-raw,channels=1 ! audioresample ! audio/x-raw,rate=44100 ! queue ! voaacenc bitrate=128000 ! aacparse ! queue ! mux. mux. ! queue ! filesink location=/home/pi/flvpipe.flv sync=false
avconv -i /home/pi/flvpipe.flv -f flv -strict -2 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f flv rtmp://wowzaserver:1935/live/mystream -vn -c:a copy -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 3 -bsf h264_mp4toannexb /var/ramdisk/live.m3u8`

My command line looks complicated - but it's just capturing audio and video from a UVC camera, encoding everything using openmax hw acceleration, before passing it to avconv to send to a wowza server.
I don't use gstreamer to deliver to the wowza server because it seems to corrupt the stream - avconv is much more reliable at the rtmp delivery

Comment: please provide the full command line you are using and it's full output. The link you have provided takes me to an empty page.

Comment: I've added my full script and used a different file sharing service for the linked content